# Show Image when column is clicked in excel which is saved in another sheet

Tags: excel, openoffice-calc

I want to store some data in a row related to particular image and Image want to store in different sheet but in main sheet I want one column and when I click on this column then it will open the image.

This will save the space and all the data will one place.

Comment: Please provide additional detail about expected operation and what you have tried so far.  Also, is this an Excel issue solved by VBA or something else?  And what does `store some data in a row related to...` mean specifically?

Answer (score 0):

The HYPERLINK function ([Excel documentation](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/HYPERLINK-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f), [Calc documentation](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_HYPERLINK_function)) can provide clickable links from one document location to another document location.  It won't link to the images per se, but rather to the cell in (or near) which you have placed the image.